# Get combobox value from database

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, javafx, jdbc

I want to get the `ComboBox` value from database. I am trying the following code, it not return any error, but not items added to the ComboBox.

```
@FXML
private ComboBox<List> laptopos_combo;
public void filloscombo() throws SQLException
{
    String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://WIN\\SQLEXPRESS:1433;database=itinventory;" + 
    "user=sa;"+ "password=Varpal@1234;";
    Connection connect= DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);
    String query = "Select * from operatingsystem";
    
    PreparedStatement pst = connect.prepareStatement(query);
    // log.conn().prepareStatement(query);
    ResultSet os = pst.executeQuery();
    
    while(os.next())
    {
        ((List<String>) laptopos_combo).add(os.getString("os"));
    }
}
```

Comment: [mcve] please - btw: that code snippet looks completely wrong (why do you have a List as data item? when the query returns a imple string? and type-casting a comboBox to list?) .. please make sure you understand how to use comboBox (there are tons of tutorials/example to learn from). And stick to java naming conventions in public communication :)

Answer (score 0):

```
public ArrayList<Object> selectAllObjects() {
        ArrayList<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
             String connectionUrl 
             ="jdbc:sqlserver://WIN\\SQLEXPRESS:1433;database=itinventory;" + 
             "user=sa;"+ "password=Varpal@1234;";
             Connection connect= DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);
             Statement stmt = connect.createStatement();
             ResultSet result = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT QUERY");
             while (result.next()) {
                Object obj = new Object();
                obj.setId(result.getInt(1));
                //setters
                list.add(payment);
            }
        } catch (SQLException se) {
            se.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (connect != null) {
                try {
                    connect.close();
                } catch (SQLException se) {
                    se.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        return list;
    }
```

And then you can call that function, save it into another Arraylist and set it like so:

```
comboBox.setItems(arraylist);
comboB.setValue(arraylist.get(0));
```

Comment: show some error in code                                                                                                                         1. obj.setId(result.getInt(1));  error: the method setId(int ) is unidentified for type object      2. what payment argument does in list.add(payment); and where i create it                         3. connect is local variable in try block and not work in finally block. When i declare it outside try, it not works

Comment: @SukhmanjitSingh ur supposed to replace object with your model object...this is example code. list.add(payment) should be list.add(obj) was a copy paste error

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change the item type of the ComboBox from List to String, because you wanna add a string value to the ComboBox, try this:

```
@FXML
private ComboBox<String> laptopos_combo;
public void filloscombo() throws SQLException {
    String connectionUrl ="jdbc:sqlserver://WIN\\SQLEXPRESS:1433;database=itinventory;" +
            "user=sa;"+ "password=Varpal@1234;";
    Connection connect= DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);
    String query="Select * from operatingsystem";

    PreparedStatement pst = connect.prepareStatement(query);
    ResultSet os = pst.executeQuery();
    laptopos_combo.getItems().clear(); // Add this line to remove all items before you add the database one
    while(os.next()) {
        laptopos_combo.getItems().add(os.getString("os"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I tried below code but show only first value. I did it by implements initializable interface

```
try
{
    String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://WIN\\SQLEXPRESS:1433;database=itinventory;" + 
        "user=sa;"+ "password=Varpal@1234;";
    Connection connect= DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);
    String query="Select * from operatingsystem";
    
    PreparedStatement pst = connect.prepareStatement(query);
            // log.conn().prepareStatement(query);
    ResultSet os = pst.executeQuery();
    
    while(os.next())
    {
        ObservableList<String> value = 
  FXCollections.observableArrayList(os.getString("os"));
         System.out.println(value);
        laptopos_combo.setItems(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: please don't add details to your questions as answer - instead edit your question to include them :)